Модели словообразования
Интересует вопрос: можно ли однозначно утверждать, каким способом образовалось слово?
Для примера возьмем глагол "напевать".
Какая словообразовательная модель будет верна?

1)Петь-напеть-напевать 2)Петь-напевать

Способ образования суффиксальный или все же приставочно-суффиксальный?


Могу предположить, что в этой теме могут использоваться обе модели.

Вариант 1. Петь — напеть — напевать. Суффиксальный способ образования. Этот вариант соответствует словарю Тихонова и, вероятно, считается основным в школьной программе.
Вариант 2. Петь — напевать. Префиксально-суффиксальный способ образования.

С чем связаны такие выводы? Посмотрим значение слов в толковом словаре:

Большой толковый словарь русского языка
НАПЕТЬ, -пою, -поёшь; св. 1. чего. Пропеть, спеть много 
(песен, арий и т.п.). Сколько колыбельных бабушка за свою 
жизнь напела! 2. что. Разг. Передать голосом (мотив, мелодию 
и т.п.). Н. песню. Н. мотив. 3. что. Спеть для звукозаписи 
(на пластинку, плёнку и т.п.). Н. арию на пластинку. // Спев 
для звукозаписи, заполнить (пластинку, плёнку и т.п.). Н. 
пластинку, две кассеты. 4. (что на кого). Разг.-сниж. 
Наговорить много неприятного, обидного и т.п. или 
насплетничать на кого-л. Н. на соседей, на начальника. Он 
такое напоёт, что уши вянут. НАПЕВАТЬ (см.). Напеваться, 
 -ается; страд.

НАПЕВАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; нсв. 1. к Напеть. 2. (что). Петь 
(обычно тихо, вполголоса). Н. песенку. Тихонько н. себе под 
нос. Напеваться, -ается; страд. Напевание, -я; ср.

Мы видим,что у напевать два значения: (1) форма несов. вида для напеть Разг. Передать голосом (мотив, мелодию и т.п.). Н. песню. Н. мотив. и (2) собственное значение по словарю..

Далее смотрим Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц русского языка Ефремовой Т.Ф.

Там есть словообраз.единица НА...ВА(ТЬ) и указан в примере глагол напевать. Также есть: НА...ЫВА(ТЬ), НА...ИВА(ТЬ).
Значение: ослабленность или неполнота действия.  Это как раз соответствует собственному  значению глагола напевать по словарю.

Есть ли какой-то способ однозначно решить, какой вариант корректен, если решается тест с забитыми ответами?

Я бы выбрала вариант по Тихонову, это известное школьное пособие.  Лишние нюансы там не нужны, а Ефремову мало кто читает. Но мне по слуху ближе вариант 2, то есть значение петь тихо, вполголоса. Про Ефремову лучше вспомнить, когда защищаешь свой выбор.
